# ADF pipeline going into queue state

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Copy activity where the source and destination are both Blobs.
When i tried the copy pipeline previously,it ran successfully.
But currently it is going into queue state for a long time i.e. 30 minutes.

[image]

Can i know the reason behind it?

Comment: Does the pipeline eventually execute? It could be an issue with regional resource availability.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer/solution to the problem. Since i cannot comment yet, had to put it in the Answer section. It could be delay in assigning the compute resources. Please check the details.
You can check the details by hovering mouse pointer between Name and Type beside Copy.

[image]

Comment: We only get that details option when the pipeline is either in progress or completed. But my pipeline is in Queue state